# Find records with "ghost" childs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have Box and Toy entities.

```
class Box < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :toy
end

class Toy < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :box
end
```

Something corrupted my data, and some toys were deleted.
How can I pick all Boxes that has link to Toy not existed any more?

I can write complex SQL, but want to feel Rails magic to do something like:

```
Box.where(toy: does_not_exist_any_more)
```

Returned boxes should have not nil but **number** in toy_id field, and where  is no record in toys with id = **number**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Box.where.not(id: Toy.all.pluck(:box_id))
```

This:

```
Toy.all.pluck(:box_id)
```

will give you all of the `Box` ids that are referenced by any instance of `Toy`.

Then this:

```
Box.where.not(id: Toy.all.pluck(:box_id))
```

will give you all of the boxes that are not currently reference by some instance of `Toy`.

Comment: Rather than loading them all into an array with `pluck` you could `Box.where.not(id: Toy.select(:box_id))` to use a subquery and let the database do the work.

Comment: @muistooshort - Thanks. My understanding is that `select` instantiates `Toy` whereas `pluck` does not. Is that correct? Any thoughts on relative performance, overhead, or whatever?

Comment: `Toy.select(:box_id)` just builds a `select box_id from toys` query without instantiating anything (beyond the query builder objects of course). Then you put that relation into a `where` call and you end up with `where id not in (select id from toys)` in the SQL and the database does all the work. `id: Toy.all.pluck(:box_id)` does a `select box_id from toys` to pull all the ids out of the database into a Ruby array, then that array gets turned into a string and sent back to the database. Keeping everything in the database should be faster.

Comment: You could also do a LEFT JOIN and look for NULLs. Adding a foreign key constraint inside the database would also be a good idea so that this sort of thing can't happen again.